# Can we auto add or suggest add the "main" tag if OP's using a "version" tag of the main tag?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

For example, from [python-2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.7) tag wiki:

> #### Tagging recommendation:
>
> Use the [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) tag for all Python related questions. If you believe your question includes issues specific to the incompatible Python 2.x or Python 3.x, then in addition to the main tag use [python-2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.x) or [python-3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x). If you believe your question may be even more specific, you can include a version specific tag such as [python-2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.7).

---

So the problem is, sometimes someone always just add [python-2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.x), [python-3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x), or even [python-2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.7), [python-3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.5) instead of use all of them like:

> [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) [python-2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.x) [python-2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.7)

However I'd suggest that when someone only use [python-2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.x), add a [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) tag automatically. At least show something like:

> Please remember add the main tag **with** the specific version tag.

---

I think it's a problem because [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34050113/how-does-the-min-max-function-on-a-nested-list-work). I think it's a good question, but since it's tags are incorrect (I mean it only tagged [python-2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.7)) before my edit, so it only received...about 20 viewed IIRC.

Comment: Better solution: allow only `python(2|3)?` tags

Comment: @Braiam: Sounds good, since actually only `python(2|3)` have the big different :P

Comment: There are certainly other places that this would be useful. `c++` on `c++11` questions, `java` on `java-8` questions. Idk why no one picked this up