# How to encourage users to tag with non-versioned tags

Tags: discussion, tags

I'm just wondering if there's something the Stack team can do to to eliminate question holes by over-specific version tags.

I saw a question with very little activity because it was only tagged [ios4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios4) and [ios9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios9). Could there be a feature here where the [ios4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios4) (and other variants) are related to [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios). If there is only version specific tags, it might be nice to have a warning suggesting to use [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios) *in addition* to the version-specific tag. We already have something like this for [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql), but to point at a specific flavor of SQL.

Thoughts?

Comment: Similar: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312932/can-we-auto-add-or-suggest-add-the-main-tag-if-ops-using-a-version-tag-of-t?rq=1

Comment: I hate version tags.

Comment: I may be playing devil's advocate here, but I am having an issue that is strictly on iOS9, so I can see how an `ios9` tag would be useful... I've come across a lot of similar issues on various other versions of iOS that have either been fixed in an update or are completely unrelated. On that same note, I feel that users not looking specifically for the proper version would have a hard time finding general questions about iOS, for example.

Comment: @Vemonus i'm not saying to abolish the version tags, just make the questions more discoverable.

Comment: Ah, I see. What about having it so that if a user searches for things with an `ios` tag, they can see all `ios` tags (e.g. `ios4`, `ios9`), but if they search specifically for, say, `ios9`, then only `ios9` tagged posts will appear? Possibly also `ios` tags, but that's dependent on if everyone adopts tagging their posts with versions, huh?

Comment: @Vemonus im talking about the other way.

Comment: I think you are tackling the problem the wrong way: people use version tags because they think specificity is a good thing... is not. At least not if you want to get answers to your question. I find myself most of the time ignoring whatever "version" information.

Comment: I like this suggestion, I most frequently edit questions with a sole `Python-3.x` tag, adding `Python` to make them more visible.

Comment: Can versioned tags be treated as children of the main tag, so they show up in searches for the parent?

Comment: @ssube been there, tried that. Declined with good reason. [Implicit tagging hierarchy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/61433) THAT IT IS WAY TOO COMPLEX FOR LITTLE TO NO GAIN.

Comment: @Braiam no gain, 6 years ago. That was before most of the big languages were being updated annually.

Comment: @ssube And because of that do python-3.5.1 stops being python when it's updated to 3.5.2?

Comment: @Vemonus Doesn't that basically already exist? Do a search for [ios*] and the search will wildcard-match and give you results from [ios], [ios4], [ios9], etc. Seems like the core problem would be answerers only searching for big overarching tags when they could easily be looking at questions from all the versions, too.

Comment: @Mikegrann, I didn't know that was a search feature. I'll use that in the future, thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92375/partial-subset-tag

Comment: Interestingly enough, I often see the reverse problem: not specifying the version *at all*, especially when the version actually does matter for the behavior.

Comment: What about special tag extension that contains and counts for both, the main tag and the version? Example: [ios,9] counts as both [ios] and [ios9]

Comment: @DanielAWhite, downvoting with no stated reason seems to be particularly prevalent here on Meta. I think it should be banned. Sometimes I feel that any question that appears critical of the SO status quo gets an automatic downvote.

Comment: @MichaelKay If you ban downvoting without comment you'll get fun comments or stock comments instead. Do you want that? I guess not. Downvoting on meta just means disagreement, not that the contribution is not useful or hasn't been thoroughly researched (unfortunately the tooltips do not reflect this). You just have to adjust your base level. Any question that appears critical and gets a significant number of upvotes is a success and a strong hint that there might be something to it. Don't judge based on the score alone but normalize the score based on context (other similar questions).

Comment: @jpmc26 But one problem with version-specific tags is that they become unreliable with age. If I tag something with [program-v3] because only the latest Program has the feature I'm talking about, by the time Program 4 comes out my issue is no longer specific to v3!

Comment: @MichaelKay Downvoting on meta has a different meaning than on the main site. It means disagreement with the discussion, i.e. by downvoting this question you are effectively saying "who cares about version tags. The *status quo* is fine". Sure you could post an answer that argues against what the OP proposes, which would enable the community to vote for that too, but you can just give your opinion with that vote.

Comment: @Bakuriu It could also mean "you are trying to solve the wrong problem".

Comment: @Braiam hence i wish there was clarification.

Answer (score -4):

You can't win this; the problem is too big. There's no way to force users (especially new users) to do anything (otherwise we'd have no concerns over question quality). There's too many questions that use these tags to eliminate them.

The only thing we can really do is fix what we can, and try to avoid problems with the rest.

Instead of version tags, you should use the main tag and a "feature" tag, including the specific version in the body of the post, if necessary. For example, use [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java)[streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/streams) to refer to the Java 8 feature of streams. This is what Code Review does.

You can skirt around the rest of the issue by using tabs in the new nav. In my "Java" tab, I follow [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), [java-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-8) and a whole bunch of other Java-related tags.

---

You can find a whole number of too specifically tagged posts easily by searching. Then, you can retag those questions.

Example: [`-[java][java-8]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-8%20not%20java?mode=all)

Comment: Upvoted for including an example of finding too-specific questions.

Comment: Not entirely a fan of this approach, since it creates tags centered around language features which are specific to a particular version of the language as opposed to the actual version of the language.  This may be a tacit acknowledgment that version tags are preferable, but this is more of a tricky issue than you're making it out to be.  (Also - the right tag to use would be [tag:java-stream].)