# Choosing Qt tags

Tags: discussion, tags

Currently there are a few levels of tags related to Qt:

- The general [qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qt)
- Major versions, e.g. [qt4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qt4)
- Minor versions, e.g. [qt4.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qt4.8)

Should I use all 3 levels? E.g. when asking a question and using Qt 4.8, tag [qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qt), [qt4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qt4), and [qt4.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qt4.8)? What if I don't have 3 free tag slots left, which should I prefer?

This is actually two separate questions:

1. Philosophically, which tags *should* I use?
2. Realistically, which tags are more likely to attract readers watching these tags and get an answer?

Also, this is about the case where I'm *using*, for example, Qt 4.8, but I'm not necessarily sure that it's *specific* to Qt 4.8 (might apply to, say, Qt 5.x, or 4.7, etc. without me knowing).

Comment: related, if not  dupe: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265844/should-i-not-use-the-generic-tag-if-my-solution-is-limited-to-a-specific-version

Comment: I would argue that the minor release is unnecessary as a tag. If the minor version is critical (e.g. backporting a feature not available in the release you are stuck with), that belongs in the question body. I would tag current Qt questions with the qt5 tag, however, solely because Qt6 will one day arrive.

Comment: I was just asking this question again here, and the auto search turned up this post, which turned out to be mine. Funny that.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Always** use the generic tag [qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qt). You can think of this as a "master" tag. This solves the realistic problem, ensuring that Qt experts get eyes on your question.

And since Qt is a framework, you should probably also add a language tag, if for no other reason than to indicate what language you'd prefer to receive code samples in.

**Only** use the version-specific tag if your issue is known or believed to be version-specific. Do *not* throw a version-specific tag on your question just because you are using that particular version. Place this information in words in your question instead.

When choosing a version-specific tag, pick the most descriptive (specific?) one that you can. So if the problem is specific to version 4.8, use [qt4.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qt4.8), but if it afflicts Qt 4.*x*, then use [qt4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qt4). You can use both [qt4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qt4) and [qt4.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qt4.8) if you want and you have the room.

Version-specific tags are *also* useful when you are limited to using a particular (older) version of a language or framework, and want answerers to take that into account. So, for example, if Qt 5 is out and might have a better way of solving the problem, tag your question [qt4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qt4) if you cannot upgrade to Qt 5 and want to see solutions that will work on Qt 4. (This is especially common in the C++ world, where you need to explicitly tag a question [c++03](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b03) if you don't want to see C++11- or C++17-based solutions.)

**Generally speaking** (I am not a Qt expert), a version point-*x* tag seems *way* too specific to be useful. Unless that point-*x* version introduced a bunch of breaking changes or was especially buggy (yet popular), there is just no need for a minor-version tag. The major version tag is sufficient.

Comment: "Do not throw a version-specific tag on your question just because you are using that particular version." [\[citation needed\]](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333015)

Comment: The logic is simple. The tag system is for the categorization of questions. The fact that you happen to be using a particular version of a framework, language, or IDE does not change how your question should be classified, any more than the fact that you have a triple monitor setup, a fuchsia desktop background, and prefer to drink tea. Or the fact that you're running Windows 7. All kinds of miscellaneous details of dubious applicability do not belong in the tags. If you think they're important, mention them in the body of the question.

Comment: I know that. I'm an ferocious advocated of that.