# Should specific version tags be synonyms to the "base" tag?

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonym-process

It has come to my attention that if I post a question that is about Qt 5.8 specifically, respectively tagged with [qt5.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qt5.8) it won't show in the [qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qt) tag channel. I could have also wasted another tag to specify that [qt5.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qt5.8) also means [qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qt), but I felt like it would not be the optimal solution.

Or maybe there is another way to have questions tagged with a specific version also appear in the [base](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/base) tag category?

Comment: @rene - without elaboration that statement is lost at me. How does a specific version of say a framework does not apply to the framework itself?

Comment: @dtech One possibility is that the framework has changed significantly enough from one version to the other that lumping both into a single tag becomes counterproductive.

Comment: Closely related (possibly a dupe): [Simple tag hierarchy to aid in searching / browsing](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255245)

Comment: I does sound like giving precedence of "eventuality" over "prevailing common sense". How frequent would such instances be? What is the benefit to harm ratio?

Comment: @MartijnPieters - the one you refer to is kind a similar, but more stretched. I am talking `qt5.8` to `qt` here, not `winapi` to `windows`. I am talking "version to base" not "related" tags.

Comment: @dtech: which is why I didn't immediately dupe-close it. But the answer there links to a *lot* of prior discussion. So far, the idea of complicating the tag system by adding a hierarchy (be it for version-tags or more) has not been received all that well.

Comment: I mean `winapi` is definitely about `windows`, but windows is not all about `winapi`. Whereas `qt5.8` is still very much `qt`. So without needless complexity, tags that are a popular tag + a version number maybe get loosely associated to get better exposure?

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312932/can-we-auto-add-or-suggest-add-the-main-tag-if-ops-using-a-version-tag-of-t

Comment: @rene - yeah `qt(5.8)` would do the trick if such a format is avaiable.